# Patching without downtime in postgres

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, patch

Just wanted to know if i'm patching my postgres database and I should not have any downtime whatsoever what should i do ? (I'm patching both my Master and Slave Databases)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "patching"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind running modified PostgreSQL servers, you can run a cluster solution like [BDR](https://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/bdr/) or [Postgres-XL](http://www.postgres-xl.org/).

With standard PostgreSQL, you can use streaming replication. First upgrade the standby, then manually fail over to the standby, upgrade the primary and use it as new standby server.

All these solutions require that you have a connection pooler like [pgBouncer](https://pgbouncer.github.io/) that allows you to redirect client connections between the servers.